# Regular expression or function to search for word and return the next one

Tags: c#, php, regex, string

I'm looking for a function/regular expression that finds the given word and retruns the next one for example:
Giving the input     `"is"`

and searching in this string

```
"the force is strong with you but you are not a jedi yet"
```

would return     `"strong"`

Searching for "you" would return an array containing `{"but","are"}`.

Im'm looking for a code sample preferably in PHP or C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

`(?:\bis\b)\s*(\b\w*\b)`

[image]

[image]

## Example

```
PHP Code Example: 
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/(?:\bis\b)\s*(\b\w*\b)/i',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Is that
            [1] => is strong
            [2] => is that
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => that
            [1] => strong
            [2] => that
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using C#:

```
var search = "you";
var str = "the force is strong with you but you are not a jedi yet";
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, search + @"\s(\w+)");

foreach (Match word in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

This assumes that there is a single space after the word you search for. The same regular expression would work in PHP (obviously without the `@` and with delimiters).

Comment: I like your solution, but prefer Denomales's which takes in account multiple spaces.

Answer (score 0):

C# sample:

```
var words = new List<string>();
string wordToSearch = "you";
string strTargetString = @"the force is strong with you but you are not a jedi youu yet";

string strRegex = string.Format(@"(\b{0}\b)\s+(\b.+?\b)", wordToSearch);
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);


foreach(Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    string word = myMatch.Groups[2].Value;
    words.Add(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A php function without regex :

```
$str = "the force is strong with you but you are not a jedi yet";
$res = getTheNextOne('you', $str);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($res,true) . '</pre>';
//Array
//(
//  [0] => but
//  [1] => are
//)

function getTheNextOne($needle, $str) {

    $res = array();

    $tmp = explode(' ', $str);
    $length = count($tmp);

    //$length-1 as there is no next word for the last one
    for($i=0; $i < $length-1; $i++) {
        if($tmp[$i] == $needle) {
            $res[] = $tmp[$i+1];
        }
    }

    $nbFound = count($res);

    if($nbFound == 0) {
        return null;
    } elseif ($nbFound == 1) {
        return $res[0];
    } else {
        return $res;
    }
}
```